# Trouble serving static files with my goapp through nginx

Tags: html, nginx, go, static-files

I am making my first go app on an Ubuntu Server. When I run my server using either an executable or simply go run main.go, I get the initial html page to render, but none of the css, images, or js. The routes also take me to a 404 page. The only thing that seems to pass is the index.html(which is named index.gohtml as a template for go)

All my assets are loaded when I run it on localhost and ip:port configuration on the server, however when I use nginx the assets are not loading in at all. I am assuming because of these factors that nginx is where I am coming across my issue.

Below is what I have so far. This is my first time using nginx so I am unaware of what is necessary to configure it properly.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;

            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }
```

}

Comment: are the links for your files working without the nginx proxy?. What is the generated code of your index template?, this it's to see what is the URL for the files. Also, if you go app is serving the hole site without any external resource, you don't have to set `root`, `index` and `try_files`

Comment: The files are loading without the nginx proxy. The refs in index are pointing to the static files from the index's location. I have images, JS, and CSS that I need to load.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to separate the `try_files` and `proxy_pass` into separate locations:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
}
```

If the static file does not exist, the request will be forwarded to the service running on port 8001.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Nothing changes after reconfiguring. Would the root configuration have something to do with it?